# How do I fix scram authentication errors when connecting DBeaver to a docker postgresql container?

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

### Background:

I am using a docker-compose file to run a Postgresql container. Upon upgrade, I was unable to log in using DBeaver (v23.1.2), getting the following error in DBeaver:

```
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "[username]"
```

Docker log errors indicated that I was unable to log in due to scram authentication:

```
postgres_1  | 2023-07-27 23:49:11.288 UTC [48] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "[USERNAME]"
postgres_1  | 2023-07-27 23:49:11.288 UTC [48] DETAIL:  User "[USERNAME]" does not have a valid SCRAM secret.
postgres_1  |   Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 100: "host all all all scram-sha-256"
```

#### Old docker-compose file of old PostgreSQL version:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[USERNAME]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[DATABASENAME]
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres-12:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

#### New docker-compose file for upgraded PostgreSQL (causes scram error)

I changed the docker-compose file to this when upgrading:

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[USERNAME]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[DATABASENAME]    
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/postgres-15:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:5432:5432"
```

Before doing so I did a database dump from the old, and when the new version was started I imported it into the new database. When I connected using DBeaver I was unable to log in receiving the above mentioned scram authentication errors.

Comment: See here [client authentication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-password.html). Change `scram-sha-256` to `md5` as: *To ease transition from the md5 method to the newer SCRAM method, if md5 is specified as a method in pg_hba.conf but the user's password on the server is encrypted for SCRAM (see below), then SCRAM-based authentication will automatically be chosen instead.*. This covers you both ways.

Comment: You should show the exact error message from both client and server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the password in the posgres database is using md5, not scram. The upgraded version of postegresql has the following setting in pg_hba.conf:

```
host all all all scram-sha-256
```

This setting requires that only scram encryption be used by clients. However, the password in the database is hashed by md5 so  no match occurs.

### Overview:

- change pg_hba.conf back to allow connections without scram,
- connect with DBeaver client
- re-encrypt the password this time using scram (by simply replacing with your same password),
- restore the original scram line in the pg_hba.conf
- restart the database

### Specific Steps to Solution:

#### 1. Set PGDATA environmental variable.

Edit your docker file to add the PGDATA environmental variable to make sure that the configuration directory is being found by setting your environmental variable:

```
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=[USERNAME]
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=[PASSWORD]
      - POSTGRES_DB=[DATABASENAME]   
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data [this should match the path inside the container, not the local volume path - see the volumes statement]
```

### 1. Edit pg_hba.conf to allow unencrypted connections

In my docker-compose file above, my configuration pg_hba.conf resides on my docker host at volumes/postgres-15/pg_hba.conf.   Edit as follows commenting out the scram line, and changing it to trust.

```
#host all all all scram-sha-256
host all all all trust
```

#### 2. Edit postgresql.conf to specify scram.

Edit volumes/postgres-15/postgresql.conf to set authentication method as scram. This should already be the default on a new installation:

```
 password_encryption = scram-sha-256
```

This will tell postgres to encrypt any new passwords in scram which will occur when you replace your password after connecting through DBeaver.

#### 3. Restart your postgresql server.

I do this by `docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d; docker-compose logs -f`.

#### 3. Connect using Dbeaver.

#### 4. Check for Scram Unencrypted Users.

In DBeaver, open a new sql dialog by typing `ctrl-]` (or use the menu `SQL Editor->New Script`) and run the following sql select to see the passwords in the database that are not encrypted in scram:

```
SELECT
    rolname, rolpassword ~ '^SCRAM-SHA-256\$' AS has_upgraded
FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolcanlogin;
```

[image]

The result of the sql command (not shown in screen shot) should be "False" for any password not encrypted in scram:

[image]

#### 5. Replace passwords to encrypt in scram.

For each use that has a false result, reset the password so it gets encrypted into scram by selecting the connection, right clicking, selecting `Security`, then `Change user password`.  Since we are not changing passwords just re-encrypting into scram, enter the old password twice - once in "New Password" and then in "Verify". Click `OK`.

[image]

[image]

#### 6. Verify Passwords are encrypted.

Rerun the sql script above and your password should now show "True".

[image]

#### 7.  Restore pg_hba.conf to require scram.

Now go back to your server running your docker container and reverse what was done in step one - specifying that all users must use scram. I do this by editing `volumes/postgres-15/pg_hba.conf`, deleting or commenting out the trust line, and restoring the scram line:

```
host all all all scram-sha-256
#host all all all trust [or delete]
```

#### 8. Restart your docker container

I do this by `docker-compose down; docker-compose up -d; docker-compose logs -f`.

#### 9. Re-connect DBeaver.

You should now be able to login using DBeaver scram authentication without errors.